# Flux. Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

Find the flux of $F(x, y, z) = \langle-x, -y, z^3\rangle$ through the surface $S$ when $S$ is the part of the cone

$$z =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

that lies between the planes $z = 1$ and $z = 3$, oriented upwards.

- If I use the usual method, Im getting $1712\pi/15$
- If I use divergence theorem, Im getting $1916\pi/15$

Is the divergence theorem not valid in here? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the divergence theorem is valid. But you're applying it to a region whose boundary consists of not only that surface $S$, but also two disks: $\Sigma_1 = \{x^2+y^2\le 1, z=1\}$ and $\Sigma_2 = \{x^2+y^2\le 3, z=3\}$. In addition, be careful with the orientations on those disks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do you identify how many surface it have? I'm still confused about simple solid regions.

Comment: Start by drawing a sketch; your artwork needn't be perfect.